# Can you explain this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't understand how this query worked. Is it some advanced feature of mysql which I am not able to understand?

```
select A.id from A where A.id in (select B.id from  B where B.id = A.id)
```

Comment: Select `id`s which exist in both A and B.

Comment: Not that advanced. A correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

A unnecessary correlated subquery which is fetching all rows where id of table A matches id of table B. It can as well be written like

```
select id 
from A 
where id in (select id from  B)
```

(OR) Using `INNER JOIN`

```
select a.id 
from A a 
join B b on a.id = b.id;
```

(OR) using `WHERE EXISTS`

```
select a.id 
from A a
where exists (select 1 from B where id = a.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a subquery or nested query. The inner query gives an array of results and then the outer query uses this array to filter the rows of the A table.
The whole query doesn't make sense though...
A better query would be:

```
SELECT A.id from A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is just nothing but inner join only

```
SELECT A.id from A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id;
```